# Bitwise logical operator and shift operator

Tags: c, bit-manipulation, operator-keyword, shift

This code is an example from  a book that the problem require to change decimal to binary number using bitwise `AND` operator and the `shift` operator.
I cannot understand the code although had tried to understand this code using debug compiler.

Suppose that for `a` and `b` the user input is `10` and `8`

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>


int count_bits (unsigned x)
{

    int bits=0;
    while(x){
        if (x&1U)bits++;
            x>>=1;


    } return bits;
}

int int_bits(void)
{
    return count_bits(~0U);
}

void print_bits(unsigned x)
{
    int i;
    for(i=int_bits(x)-1;i>=0;i--)
        putchar(((x>>i)&1U)?'1':'0');
}
int main(void)
{
 unsigned a,b; /*suppose user input a=10 b=8*/
 printf("enter two positive integer value=\n");
 printf("a=  "); scanf("%u",&a);
 printf("b:  "); scanf("%u",&b);

 printf("\na   =");  print_bits(a);
 printf("\na   =");  print_bits(b);
    return 0;
}
```

In `int_bits` function what actually `(~0U)` does? I this meaning to change `0` to `1`?

I know it calls `count_bits` function and return count bits(~0) value but why the `x` here is somewhat random memory address like `4294967295`?

Maybe is it because `int int_bits(void)` and `int_bits()` so no parameter and `x` change from `10` to a random address?

And the `count_bits` function is here to count how many bits?

```
while (4294967295)  {
if(x&1u)-> (means compare x last digit value with 1) if true, bits ++;
x>>=1; }-> this mean to shift 1 digit of x to right which mean to divide with 2 until quotien is 0
```

and when I tried to debug I got `32` for bits value
Why produce `32`? is this relate to `(~0U)` so all bits were `1` or the remains of division?

```
print_bits (unsigned x) function, is to produce the result
for(i=int_bits()-1;i>=0;i--)
putchar(((x>>i)&1u)?'1':'0')
the x in this value is 10,8 (user input)
and i is 31 from return bits
32-1=31 will be looping until 0
```

`10>>30` means shift `31` to right in just `10`?

How it can produce `1010`?

What this code actually compare to produce `1010`?

Actually the program also produce `32` digit with `1010` in the end.

Comment: If your book uses such words as "convert decimal to binary" you better throw it away. There are no decimal numbers in your program.

Comment: @n.m. Decimal number is the input from the user as a and b variable?

Comment: Yes the user inputs numbers in decimal but when they reach your variables `a` and `b` they are no longer decimal.

Comment: The code is also really bad. `int_bits(x)` is named like it counts bits *in x*, but no, it doesn't use its argument and count the total number of bits in an unsigned number. And the program calls this function *every time it prints a bit*, though the result isn't going to ever change. Completely useless.

Comment: sorry the correct one is int_bits(void), but still dont understand the flow of this code

Comment: @n.m. "Decimal number" refers to a number being base 10.

Comment: look up the meaning of `~` in whatever book or other learning resource you are using

Comment: @n.m. `int_bits` reports the number of (non-padding) bits in an `int`, seems like a reasonable name to me

Comment: @M.M i know it negates 0 to 1 but actually what is the value of x in count_bits function and what is compare in (x & 1U) and what is the relation with (~0U)?

Comment: It doesn't look like a good book to me. `int_bits()` can be implemented simply as `sizeof (unsigned) * CHAR_BITS`.

Comment: can you explain what is going on when comparing (x&1U) bits++; x>>=1;in count_bits? i dont understand the x value here.  and in print_bits function what is the value of x and i?

Comment: @M.M why does it take an argument then?

Comment: @n.m. it doesn't

Comment: @M.M you are right I must be going blind.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
print_bits(unsigned x):
```

The code takes the last bit of the decimal number using `& 1u` (same as `& 0000000000000001`), and then uses the ternary operator to put a `'1'` if the last bit is `1` (true) and `0` if the last bit is `0` (false). The number is also shifted right one more bit in each step (due to `i` being incremented) in order to make every bit be obtained by using `& 1u`.

The `&` (and) operator compares each corresponding bit in two numbers and creates a bit of `1` if there are two `1`'s, and `0`'s in all other cases.

This:

```
int i = (0101/**/0111) & (0010/**/0101);
```

Would give `i` a value of this:

```
0000/**/0000/**/0000/**/0101 // The addition of two sets of 4 0's on the 
                             //left was due to me assuming int is 32 bits in your system.
```

Shifting this right by `1` (`>> 1`):

```
1101
```

Would produce this:

```
0110
```

Shifting multiple times allows all bits to be checked by the ternary statement.

```
count_bits (unsigned x):
```

The lowest bit of `x` is evaluated  to see if it is `1`, while incrementing 
bits, which stores the number of bits. `x` is only shifted right if `x` is `1`, 
thereby making it so that all the `1`'s in `x` are set to `0` (I would have just 
shifted `x` right with every iteration of bits (the result would be the same).

int_bits(void) converts all the 0's in count_bits to 1's so that it can be used as a way for the loop to know when to stop

Comment: & operator compare x and 1U, the x what i get is 4294967295 and compare to 0000000000000001? 4294967295, is automatically change to binary? and shift right one more bit means to divide x with 2?

Comment: @devina "Decimal" refers to being base 10, and shifting right allows the lowest bit of the number to become what used to be a higher bit, in order for the & operator to isolate that bit (instead of the original first bit every time).

Comment: i understand how & operator and  the shifting operator work but in this code while x{ if (x&1U) bits++ x>>=1;}. what is the value of x? and what is the relation with count_bits(~0)? 10 in decimal will produce 1010 in binary how the operator & work to produce 1010 in printf?

Comment: @Devina int_bits(void) converts all the 0's in count_bits to 1's so that it can be used as a way for the loop to know when to stop.

Comment: in tis code int_bits() value is 31 right? is it possible to change for condition in print_bits function to for (i=int_bits();i>0;i--?)?